# Program continues to run after method is finished

Tags: java, compilation

I have made a simple program, with two classes. The method works fine, however it continues to run after completing my method resulting in this being seen in the output and I have no idea why:

[image]

Comment: `packOfCards()` ... is this method defined anywhere?  Did your actually compile?

Comment: Definition for packOfCards()?

Comment: Sorry guys, I've correct that now.

Comment: You call `myArrayOne()` for each loop you have there, and as the method is just calling herself, the loops always gets restarted, and your recursion never ends => infinite recursion.

Comment: At the end of function `myArrayOne`, you are calling... function `myArrayOne`!!! What exactly did you expect to happen other than an infinite (recursive) execution of your program???

Comment: Hi barak, I wanted to call the myArray method from another class so I can print the values stored in the arraylist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `myArrayOne` method calls itself. That's the problem with infinite recursion.

```
public static int myArrayOne() {
        // that's the problem
        return myArrayOne();
}
```

That is probably what are you trying to accomplish:

```
 // void --> List<Integer>
 // static 
 public List<Integer>  myArrayOne() {
     ArrayList<Integer> packOfCards = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     Random rand = new Random();

     for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
     {
         pick = rand.nextInt(10);
         packOfCards.add(pick);
     }

     // myArrayOne(); --> packOfCards
     return packOfCards;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
      myattributes attributes = new myattributes();
      List<Integer> values = attributes.myArrayOne(); 
}
```

Comment: Yes I want to call that method in another class, how do I do it so it only posts the output of the method?

Comment: What do you consider output of the method? Please give an example of what the expected result should be and how are you going to use it in your another method

Comment: I want to call the method in my main method class, so I can print the values stored in the arraylist.

Comment: If you'd like to return the values from arraylist, you should return that

Comment: How would I do that Ivan? When I try to get the values stored in the arraylist at present, it prints them but then it continues to post all the other random stuff.

Comment: Thank you Ivan, I would vote up your comment but it won't yet let me.